# max fan speed rpm is not correct on dell alienware m14xr2, how to fix it?

Tags: cpu, overheating, fancontrol

im getting a problem, i have alienware m14xr2 with i7 cpu, using linux (right now im using ubuntu 18.04) also manjaro, i have a problem on heavy load my notebook is shutting down due to overheating because when the temp is for example 90c my fans are running at 4200 rpm and is not sufficient to reduce the temp and when my notebook get 105c shutdown.

in windows this not happen because the fan at that temp run at like 7200 rpm, my fan is 10.4CFM, i check my fan speed using lm-sensors and i8kmod module for dell in linux and the max speed is only 4200

I try to manipulate it manually using fan control and i8kmod trying to set the fan speed to 7200 rpm but it don't take my settings.

I already try with other board, and with new thermal paste but the same, in windows this not happens, windows is handling the fan and cpu temperature fine.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

upgrade to kernel 5.3 fix my problem not more system shutdown due to high temps, i update using

http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2017/02/ukuu-install-latest-kernels-ubuntu-linux-mint/

the problem is a bug in kernel pstate and thermald are not working so cant reduce the cpu performance under high temps